# What happens to the old state in redux on dispatch of action resulting in new state

Tags: redux

In Redux once we dispatch an action we get a new state with the updated values . What happens to the previous old state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old state is discarded. If you want to save it, you need to incorporate it as part of your state. One way to do that is explained here: [Implementing Undo History](https://redux.js.org/recipes/implementing-undo-history).

Another option is to use an "Event Sourcing" model. Where your primary state is merely an array of all actions that have transpired and you have a derivative state that reduces the array in the primary state into a "current app state." Here's an explanation of the idea for Elm: [Elm and Event Sourcing](http://marcosh.github.io/post/2016/07/09/elm-event-sourcing.html)

Comment: Doesn’t it get overwritten in the reducer

Comment: No, the reducer is a pure function and doesn't overwrite anything.

Comment: Jaha ok, it creates a new object/Array/item

Answer (score 1):

Redux state is nothing but a javascript object in your memory. There is only one version of the state, which is your latest one.

When you dispatch an action, the action handler (reducer) is a pure function which will convert your old state to new state. state should be immutable, which means the action handler does not change the old state, but get the copy of it, and then change it depends on your action type, then return it. It will looks like ("--->" means dispatch):

```
initial state ---> state 1 ---> state 2 ---> state 3 ....
```

You can install the redux [plugin in chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd), and you will see the whole history of the state.

So basically, redux does not save any old state, if you wanna trace the history, you have to do it yourself by using `Stack` or using some other libs.
I actually implement the event tracing using data structure `stack`, when state changes, you `push` to stack, when you wanna go back to previous state, you just `pop` the state and dispatch a special action to change the state, this special dispatch should not trigger `push`, very rough idea though.